# Clone element and append and remove?

Tags: jquery, append, clone

Is there a easy way to clone entire `.box` element on click `button-add` , and append it after
Also i need `button-remove` to delete only that box?

## HTML

```
    <input class="button-add" type="button" value="Clone box">

 <div class="form-group box">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <p>Article</p>
        <select class="form-control" name="article()">
            <option value="">Smoki Coko Kokos</option>
            <option value="8">Koka Kola</option>
            <option value="10">Cipiripi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Quantity</p>
        <input class="form-control" value="3" name="qty()" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input class="button-remove" type="button" value="Delete box">
    </div>
    </div>
```

this is what i have for now but does not work,

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.button-add').click(function(){

        //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box
        $('.box').clone().insertAfter(".box");
    });
    });
```

Comment: "append it each after another" needs clarifying.

Comment: Just example <div class="box">...</div><div class="box">...</div>

Comment: The cloning part of your question seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rs5zc7b2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('.box').clone()` will clone every element with class `box` on the page. You should specify which box you want to clone, and also that you want to append it after the last box:

```
$('.box:first').clone().insertAfter(".box:last");
```

Furthermore you can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to implement the remove buttons:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function() {
    $(this).closest(".box").remove();
});
```

A fiddle with these changes is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbpyyuwu/

However, this fiddle will probably not do what you want since if you remove all the boxes it will no longer work. I would suggest creating a hidden template that you clone and append instead (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbpyyuwu/1/)

Comment: Nice. This worked, how to clone first if the content is hidden initially or removed all the element

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to move element to new div? Try this:

```
$('.box').detach().appendTo(".box");
```

Edit:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/ccj6g7er/1/)

Comment: No i want to clone that box each afther another

Comment: what about: $('.box').clone().appendTo(".box");

Comment: try this fiddle is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Click handlers need to be delegated to a static ancestor node (eg. `document`) so that click functionality (add and remove) is attached to cloned boxes.

I expect you want something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.button-add', function() {
        $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);//or maybe .insertAfter('.box:last'), as per Ninsly's answer
    }).on('click', '.button-remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Check this link with demo to add remove div jquery
[Here is the JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kamalswami/0ed94p74/1/) and you can check also below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div_clone = null;
  div_clone = $('.template').clone();
  $('.button-add').click(function() {
    //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box
    var _elm = div_clone.clone();
    _elm.find('.box-title').html('Other Address');
    _elm.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    _elm.find('.remove_btn').show();
    _elm.appendTo('#clone_here');
  })

  $(document).on("click", ".remove_btn", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
    $e.closest('.template').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="button-add" type="button" value="Clone box">
<div class="form-group box template">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <p>Article</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="article()">
      <option value="">Smoki Coko Kokos</option>
      <option value="8">Koka Kola</option>
      <option value="10">Cipiripi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <p>Quantity</p>
    <input class="form-control" value="3" name="qty()" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input style="display:none;" class="remove_btn" type="button" value="Delete box">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="clone_here">
</div>
```